C# winform ListBox Unselect by Item
I have a problem with click cancel

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lbItems.Items.Add("1");
            lbItems.Items.Add("2");
            lbItems.Items.Add("3");
            lbItems.Items.Add("4");
            lbItems.Items.Add("5");
            lbItems.Items.Add("6");

            lbItems.MouseDown += LbItems_MouseDown;
            lbItems.SelectedValueChanging // not found
        }

        private void LbItems_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
          // I want to cancel click to the item in ListBox
        }
    }
}

I thought there was a SelectedValueChanging event that allows you to cancel the selection of an element and stay on the old one. Maybe replace the ListBox with another control from DevEXpress? But which one?

An alternative to using a third-party control would be to make your own extended ListBoxEx class that implements SelectedIndexChanging (make sure to swap it out manually in the MainForm.Designer.cs file.)
class ListBoxEx : ListBox
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            var e = new SelectedValueChangingEventArgs(IndexFromPoint(new Point((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF, (int)m.LParam >> 16)));
            SelectedValueChanging?.Invoke(this, e);
            if (e.Cancel) return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectedValueChangingEventArgs>? SelectedValueChanging;
}

class SelectedValueChangingEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{
    public SelectedValueChangingEventArgs(int index) => Index = index;
    public int Index { get; }
}


Here's a minimal example of being able to select an item programmatically (i.e. by making selection indirectly using the NumericUpDownControl) while disallowing mouse selection. This might not be "exactly" what you're trying to achieve, but the point is to simply demonstrate having control of whether the mouse event causes selection or not.

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbItems.Items.Add("1");
        lbItems.Items.Add("2");
        lbItems.Items.Add("3");
        lbItems.Items.Add("4");
        lbItems.Items.Add("5");
        lbItems.Items.Add("6");

        lbItems.SelectedValueChanging += LbItems_SelectedValueChanging;
        numericUpDown.ValueChanged += NumericUpDown_ValueChanged;
    }
    private void LbItems_SelectedValueChanging(object? sender, SelectedValueChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !_allowChange;
    }
    private void NumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbItems.SelectedIndex = lbItems.FindStringExact(numericUpDown.Value.ToString());
    }
    bool _allowChange = false; // Set true to allow mouse selection under certain conditions.
}


I think his question wasn't only to prevent mouse interaction. Someone still can use the keyboard on this listbox. Hitting 1-6 or using the up/down direction keys.

@Ralf I think you're making a good point. But wouldn't the remedy still be to catch the keyboard input in the hook? So we do agree that this example might be incomplete in that respect, but I still believe (so far) that the basic premise is sound.

You reasoned very correctly, this is exactly what I need.

Conceptually correct. Comment just about expectation management ;)  The event is called SelectedValueChanging but that its not what it does. It just gets you a cancellable Left MouseButton Down Event. Future readers might not get that.

I 100% agree on this comment, too, and I had considered the options. Ultimately, I made the choice to stick with the event name taken from OP's code, with the rationale that the extended LB might actually fire it not just here, but any time the selection is attempting to change.  In other words, bring the implementation in line with the name, instead of limiting the name to fit the partial, proof-of-concept implementation. So, basically, just trying to provide as much consistency with the wording of the question that I could.

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/q293265/listbox-selectedindex-changing

Alternatively: Use a GridControl instead of the ListBoxControl so that you have access to the BeforeLeaveRow and AfterLeaveRow events. You can style it to look just like a ListBoxControl as well.
